# Evaluate $\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} {(x+h)^{99}-x^{99}\over h}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, limits, functions

> $$\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} {(x+h)^{99}-x^{99}\over h}$$

I need to factor this in order to get a limit.

I tried:

$$\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} {[(x+h)^{33}]^3-[(x)^{33}]^3\over h}
\\ \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} {[(x+h)^{33}-(x)^{33}][(x+h)^{66}+(x+h)^{33}(x)^{33}+(x)^{66}]\over h}$$
However this does not seem helpful.

How do I approach this question?

Comment: Do you mean $h \to 0$?

Comment: yes, thank you @MisterRiemann

Comment: Hint: Limit definition of the derivative of $f(x)=x^{99}$.

Comment: Use the binomial theorem.

Comment: $A^{99} - B^{99} = (A-B)(A^{98} + A^{97}B + \cdots A B^{97} + B^{98})$

Comment: for you, $A = x+h$ while $B=x$ and $A-B = h$

Comment: The decomposition you show is not particularly helpful. Just apply the binomial theorem, and show that most of the terms disappear as $h$ goes to $0.$ Or, rewrite it saying  $a=x+h, \lim_\limits{a\to x} \frac {a^{99} - x^{99}}{a-x}$ then factor $a^{99} - x^{99} = (a-x)(a^{98} + a^{97}x + \cdots + x^{98})$  cancel the common factor and let $a = x$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're familiar with derivatives, then you can recall that
$$ f'(x) = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} $$
and consider $f(x) = x^{99}$.

Otherwise, use the binomial theorem:
\begin{align}\frac{(x+h)^{99}-x^{99}}{h} &= \frac{1}{h}\left( \sum_{k=0}^{99} \binom{99}{k}x^{99-k}h^{k} - x^{99} \right) = \frac{1}{h}\sum_{k=1}^{99}\binom{99}{k}x^{99-k}h^{k}\\&= \binom{99}{1}x^{98} + \sum_{k=2}^{99}\binom{99}{k}x^{99-k}h^{k-1}
\to 99x^{98}, \quad \text{as }h\to 0.
\end{align}

Comment: You made a typing mistake: It should be $f(x+h)-f(x)$, not $f(x+h)-f(h)$.

Comment: @MartinRosenau Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: That’s basically the derivative of $f(x) = x^{99}$.

$$\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} {(x+h)^{99}-x^{99}\over h}$$

Recall that by Binomial Expansion,

$$(a+b)^n = \sum_{r = 0}^{n} {n \choose r}a^{n-r}b^r$$

So you get

$$\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} {\color{blue}{{99 \choose 0}x^{99}}+{99 \choose 1}x^{98}h+{99 \choose 2}x^{97}h^2+…+{99 \choose n}h^{99}\color{red}{-x^{99}}\over h}$$

Cancel out the first and last terms. From here, notice if anything can be factored. Also, as another hint (for later simplifications), $${n \choose r} = \frac{n!}{r!{(n-r)!}}$$

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to realise that $h \to 0$ means $h$ is arbitrarily small so we can assume $h < 1$ and so $h > h^2 > h^3$ and that the "higher values of $h$" become "negligible"

So you are thinking way too hard.  Just use the binomial theorem to get $(x + h)^{99} = x^{99} + 99hx^{98} + \sum_{k=2}^{99} {99 \choose k} h^kx^{99-k}$ and hope that must of those higher values will become negligible.

And indeed:

$\require{cancel}\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\frac {(x + h)^{99}-x^{99}}{h }=$

$\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\frac {x^{99} + 99hx^{98} + (\sum_{k=2}^{99} {99 \choose k} h^kx^{99-k})-x^{99}}{h}=$

$\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\frac {\color{green}{\cancel{x^{99}}} + 99\color{red}{\cancel h}x^{98} + (\sum_{k=2}^{99} {99 \choose k} h^{\color{red}{\cancel {k}}k-1}x^{99-k}) - \color{green}{\cancel{x^{99}}}}{\color{red}{\cancel h}}=$

$\lim\limits_{h\to 0}(99x^{98} + \sum_{k=2}^{99} {99 \choose k}h^{k-1}x^{99-k})=$

$99x^{98} + \sum_{k=2}^{99}{99 \choose k}(\lim\limits_{h\to 0} h^{k-1})x^{99-k}=$

$99x^{98} + \sum_{k=2}^{99}{99 \choose k}(0)x^{99-k}=$

$99x^{98} + \sum_{k=2}^{99}0=$

$99x^{98}$

======

Doug M had an intriguing hint in the comments:

Considering $a^n - b^n = (a-b)(a^{n-1} + a^{n-2}b+  .... + ab^{n-2}+ b^{99})$ we get:

$(x + h)^{99} - x^{99}=$

$[(x+h) - x][(x+h)^{98} + (x+h)^{97}x + ... + (x+h)x^{97} + x^{98}]=$

$h[(x+h)^{98} + (x+h)^{97}x + ... + (x+h)x^{97} + x^{98}]$

And

$[(x+h)^{98} + (x+h)^{97}x + ... + (x+h)x^{97} + x^{98}]=$

$(x^{98} + \text{a bunch of stuff with h as a factor})+(x^{97}\cdot x + x(\text{a bunch of stuff with h as a factor}))+... (x\cdot x^{97} + x^{97}(\text{a bunch of stuff with h as a factor})) + x^{98})=$

$99x^{98} + \text { a REALLY big bunch of stuff with h as a factor}$

So $\frac {(x+h)^{98} - x^{99}}h=$

$\frac {h(99x^{98}+ \text { a REALLY big bunch of stuff with h as a factor}}h = $

$99x^{98}  + \text { a REALLY big bunch of stuff with h as a factor}$

... and "$ \text { a REALLY big bunch of stuff with h as a factor}$" goes to $0$ as .... it's a REALLY big bunch of stuff with $h$ as a factor.

Okay, .... it was an intriguing idea and I'm glad I did it but.... I don't think it's a very practical way to do it.

Comment: Hoping that you don't mind, I shall adopt and reuse the *REALLY big bunch of stuff*

Answer (score 0):

Because both $\lim\limits_{h\to 0}((x-h)^{99}-x^{99})=0$ and $\lim\limits_{h\to 0}h=0$ you may also use L'Hospital's rule:

$\displaystyle\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\frac{(x-h)^{99}-x^{99}}{h}=\displaystyle\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\frac{\frac{d}{dh}((x-h)^{99}-x^{99})}{\frac{d}{dh}h}=\displaystyle\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\frac{99(x-h)^{98}-0}{1}=99x^{98}$

Comment: L'Hospital is far too complicated. If you know derivatives, you can use the definition in this case.

Answer (score 0):

This limit is the derivative of $f(x)=x^{99}$. To get a generalization you can replace $99$ with $n$ where $n \in \mathbb{R}$. The limit thus translates to $\displaystyle \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{(x+h)^{n}-x^n}{h}$.

Using Binomial Theorem, which states that $(a+b)^n=\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k} a^{n-k}\ b^k$. Substituting $\begin{bmatrix}a \\ b\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}x \\ h\end{bmatrix}$. $$(x+h)^n=x^n+{n \choose 1}x^{n-1} \ h + {n \choose 2} x^{n-2} h^2+ \cdots +{n \choose n-1}xh^{n-1}+h^n$$ Putting back this result in the expression for the limit. We get the following limit $$\displaystyle \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{(x+h)^n-x^n}{h}=\displaystyle \lim_{h \to 0} \Biggl(\frac{1}{h}{n \choose 1}x^{n-1}h+\frac{1}{h}\biggl(h^2\biggl({n \choose 2}x^{n-2}+{n \choose 3}x^{n-3}h+\cdots+h^{n-2}\biggr)\biggr)\Biggr)$$ $$=\displaystyle \lim_{h \to 0} \Biggl(\biggl(nx^{n-1}\biggr)+h\biggl({n \choose 2}x^{n-2}+{n \choose 3}x^{n-3}h+\cdots+h^{n-2}\biggr)\Biggr)$$ $$=\displaystyle \lim_{h \to 0}nx^{n-1}+\underbrace{\displaystyle \lim_{h \to 0}h\biggl({n \choose 2}x^{n-2}+{n \choose 3}x^{n-3}h+\cdots+h^{n-2}\biggr)}_{=\ 0}$$
$$\implies \displaystyle \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{(x+h)^n-x^n}{h}= nx^{n-1}$$
Therefore, For $n=99$, the given limit evaluates to $99x^{98}$. Cheers